Why is Jenkins providing invalid crumbs?
I am trying to trigger a job remotely via curl request using crumb. However, Jenkins is apparently providing an invalid crumb. I am using the Default Crumb Issuer and have Enable proxy compatibility checked
curl -X POST "http://JENKINS_URL:8080/job/jobName/build?token=mytoken" -H "$(curl 'http://JENKINS_URL:8080/crumbIssuer/api/xml?xpath=concat(//crumbRequestField,":",//crumb)' -u username:password)" -v
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    78  100    78    0     0    522      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   523
*   Trying IP_ADDRESS:8080...
* Connected to JENKINS_URL (IP_ADDRESS) port 8080
> POST /job/jobName/build?token=mytoken HTTP/1.1
> Host: JENKINS_URL:8080
> User-Agent: curl/8.4.0
> Accept: */*
> Jenkins-Crumb:somevalue
> 
< HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
< Date: Tue, 02 Apr 2024 22:38:55 GMT
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID.21830c58=node0ubjfz199obyb11bwpnea8qo5a112.node0; Path=/; HttpOnly
< Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=iso-8859-1
< Content-Length: 576
< Server: Jetty(10.0.18)
< 
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 403 No valid crumb was included in the request</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 403 No valid crumb was included in the request</h2>
<table>
<tr><th>URI:</th><td>/job/myJob/build</td></tr>
<tr><th>STATUS:</th><td>403</td></tr>
<tr><th>MESSAGE:</th><td>No valid crumb was included in the request</td></tr>
<tr><th>SERVLET:</th><td>Stapler</td></tr>
</table>
<hr/><a href="https://eclipse.org/jetty">Powered by Jetty:// 10.0.18</a><hr/>

</body>
</html>


How come you have  -u username:password in the curl that gets the crumb, but not in the POST request itself? Crumb is not a replacement for authentication.

@Iterokun I just attempted with that in the second curl request by adding -u and received the same error. Also, if the issue was a lack of authentication the error would be different

When passed wrong password the error is 401 unauthorized

The reason Jenkins considers the crumb invalid is because the "outer" curl command has a different web session id from the "inner" curl command. Jenkins uses the user name, the web session id, and the IP address to validate the crumb.
There are two ways to fix it:

save the web session id that is set in the "inner" command

curl \
  --cookie cookie.txt \
  -X POST \
  "http://JENKINS_URL:8080/job/jobName/build?token=mytoken" \
  -H "$(curl \
    --cookie-jar cookie.txt 
    'http://JENKINS_URL:8080/crumbIssuer/api/xml?xpath=concat(//crumbRequestField,":",//crumb)' \
    -u username:password)" \
  -u username:password \
  -v

Notice that you need to pass the user name (and password) in both command, because it's a part of crumb validation.

Configure an API token, that doesn't require crumbs

curl \
  -X POST \
  "http://JENKINS_URL:8080/job/jobName/build?token=mytoken" \
  -u username:apiToken \
  -v

That token is different from what you have setup on the job level.

Thanks, I used api token and it worked perfectly. I was actually using api token before but I was using it with crumb and getting 400 instead of 403
